# What is the use of Collections.synchronizedList() method? It doesn't seem to synchronize the list

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, synchronization

I am trying to add `String` values to an `ArrayList` using two threads. What I want is that while one thread is adding the values the other thread should not interfere so I have used the `Collections.synchronizedList` method. But it appears that if I don't explicitly synchronize on an object the adding is done in an unsynchronized way.

Without explicit synchronized block:

```
public class SynTest {
    public static void main(String []args){
        final List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<String> synList=Collections.synchronizedList(list);
        final Object o=new Object();
        Thread tOne=new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //synchronized(o){
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                    System.out.println(synList.add("add one"+i)+ " one");
                }
                //}
            }

        });

        Thread tTwo=new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //synchronized(o){
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                    System.out.println(synList.add("add two"+i)+" two");
                }
                //}
            }

        });
        tOne.start();
        tTwo.start();
    }
}
```

The output that I got is:

```
true one
true two
true one
true two
true one
true two
true two
true one
true one
true one...
```

With the explicit synchronized block uncommented I'm stopping the interference from the other thread while adding. Once the thread has acquired the lock it is executing until it is finished.

sample output after uncommenting the synchronized block:

```
true one
true one
true one
true one
true one
true one
true one
true one...
```

So why is the `Collections.synchronizedList()` not doing the synchronization?

Comment: what do you expect? repeated `one two one two one two...`? The synchronization is on the list operation, not on the threads

Comment: look at the code of SynchronizedList to understand how the sync is implemented: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A synchronized list only synchronizes methods of this list.

It means a thread won't be able to modify the list while another thread is currently running a method from this list. The object is locked while processing method.

As an example, Let's say two threads run `addAll`on your list, with 2 different lists (`A=A1,A2,A3` and `B=B1,B2,B3`) as parameter.

- As the method is synchronized, you can be sure those lists won't be merged randomly like `A1,B1,A2,A3,B2,B3`
- You don't decide when a thread handover the process to the other thread. Each method call has to fully run and return before the other one could run. So you can either get `A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3` or `B1,B2,B3,A1,A2,A3` (As we don't know which thread call will run first).

In your first piece of code, both threads runs on the same time. And both try to `add` an element to the list. You don't have any way to block one thread except the synchronization on the `add` method so nothing prevent thread 1 from running multiple `add` operation before handing over the process to thread 2. So your output is perfectly normal.

In your second piece of code (the uncommented one), you clearly state that a thread completely lock the list from the other thread before starting the loop. Hence, you make sure one of your thread will run the full loop before the other one could access the list.

Answer (score 19):

`Collections.synchronizedList()` will synchronize all the accesses to the backed list except while iterating which still needs to be done within a synchronized block with the synchronized List instance as object's monitor.

So for example here is the code of the `add` method

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    synchronized (mutex) {return c.add(e);}
}
```

This guarantees serial access to the backed list, so if your 2 threads call `add` at the same time, one thread will acquire the lock, add its element and release the lock then the second thread will be able to acquire the lock and add its element that is why you get alternatively `one` and `two` in your output.

When you uncomment the synchronized block, the code is then

```
synchronized(o) {
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case the thread that could acquire the lock on `o` first will execute the **entire** `for` loop before releasing the lock (except if an exception is thrown), allowing the other thread to execute the content of its synchronized block, which is why you get `100` consecutive times `one` or `two` then `100` consecutive times the other value.

Answer (score 9):

This is a cool little example based on the original example and accepted answer to show what purpose `synchronizedList` serves.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SynTest {
    public static void main(String []args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<String> synList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                list.addAll(Arrays.asList("one", "one", "one"));
                synList.addAll(Arrays.asList("one", "one", "one"));
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                list.addAll(Arrays.asList("two", "two", "two"));
                synList.addAll(Arrays.asList("two", "two", "two"));
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(synList);
    }
}
```

The original `list` ends up having undefined behaviour with results such as:

```
[one, one, one] // wrong!
[one, one, one, null, null, null] // wrong!
[two, two, two] // wrong!
[one, one, one, two, two, two] // correct
```

While the synchronized `synList` has a synchronised `addAll` method and always produces one of the two correct results:

```
[one, one, one, two, two, two] // correct
[two, two, two, one, one, one] // correct
```

Comment: I am puzzled why the original list would have some null objects in its results. What's the problem here?

Comment: I think we should also mention here the use of `addAll` instead of `add`. The `addAll` method is a bulk operation unlike `add` that's why @Mo didn't encounter the same problem with original one. 
And also that's why he didn't need to use `synchronize` keyword because `Collections.synchronizedList` releases lock for every operation. In this case, lock was released after `addAll` operation.

Answer (score 4):

There is one caveat that all of the posted answers missed. Here it is: Collections.synchronizedList will return a wrapped "thread-safe" version of a List type data structure, but it will not synchroinize operations on the list. YOU still need to synchronize operations on the backing data structure to make it really multithread-safe.

If all you do is call individual methods like add(), remove(), size(), etc. You can still get a race condition because you don't know what order those operations will be executed in, unless you synchronize them. Example

```
synchronize(list){ 
 // ^ without this line the code below is not really thread-safe

        while( i++ <list.size() )
            if (testCondition( list.get() ) ) 
                  list.remove();                 

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Observable behavior is absolutely correct - the `synchronized` approach you demonstrate in your code sample does not do the same thing as the `synchronizedList` approach.

In the first case, you synchronize the whole `for`-statement, so only one thread will execute it simultaneously.
In the second case, you synchronize the collection methods themselves - that's what `synchronizedList` stands for. So the `add` method is synchronized - but not the `for` method!

Answer (score 1):

According to previous answers you need to synchronize the `synList` from access thread `tOne` and `tTwo`. In this case, you can use the monitor pattern to provides a security access - in order for threads.

Below I adapted your code to be share with others that have same problems. In this code I used only the `synList` to control access in synchronized way. Notice that it is not necessary create other object to ensure the order access from synList. 
To complement this question, see book Java Concurrency in Practice [jcip](http://jcip.net/) chapter 4 that talks about monitor design patterns that is inspired by Hoare's work

```
public class SynTest {
public static void main(String []args){
    final List<String> synList= Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    Thread tOne=new Thread(() -> {
        synchronized (synList) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                System.out.println(synList.add("add one" + i) + " one");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Thread tTwo=new Thread(()->{
        synchronized (synList) {
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                System.out.println(synList.add("add two"+i)+" two");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            }

    });
    tOne.start();
    tTwo.start();
}
```

}