# How can I ensure that every thread is working on the same object?

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency, parallel-processing

How can I ensure that every thread is working on the same object? We're executing regression on 8 threads parallel. I want to store thread-specific logs in a map, then, after run, do something with the data inside it.

```
public class Foo {
   // map with thread name as a key and queue to keep its logs
   public static final Map<String, LinkedList<String>> foofoo = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   
   
   public static void addToQueue(String threadName, String log) {
      //some logic here to add log to proper queue
   }
}
```

I want to make sure that whenever any of running threads invokes:

```
Foo.addToQueue("foo", "fooo");
```

it is accessing the same map.
Thank you for your responses. I'm kind of confused with multi threading, sorry if the question is a bit dumb.
Have a nice day! :)

Edit: in the sample up there I've used final keyword when initializing this object, because I know that it blocks objects reference. However does it solve my problem? Is there any better approach?

Comment: You can use `Collections#synchronizedList(List)`

Comment: Please provide proper sample code what the threads are supposed to do. You just post a bunch of data structures without context.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `synchronised` keyword in your method signature. When a `synchronised` method is called from a thread, it (the thread) automatically  acquires a lock on the shared object. So what you can do is make the `addToQueue` method `synchronised`. [Read more.](https://www.javatpoint.com/synchronization-in-java#:%7E:text=Java%20synchronized%20method&text=Synchronized%20method%20is%20used%20to,the%20thread%20completes%20its%20task.)

Alternatively, Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930861/what-is-the-use-of-collections-synchronizedlist-method-it-doesnt-seem-to-syn) out. It is quite an informative thread on `Collections.synchronisedList`. Have a working [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58040498/6200672) also.

Answer (score 0):

### My understanding

1. Aggregate information per thread
2. Collect this aggregated data in the main thread

### Sample Code

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ThreadParallel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> input = IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        class ThreadSpecific {

            final String threadName;
            final String num;

            ThreadSpecific(int num) {
                threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                this.num = Integer.toString(num);
            }

            public String getThreadName() {
                return threadName;
            }

            public String getNums() {
                return num;
            }
        }

        Map<String, List<String>> result = input.parallelStream()
            .map(i -> new ThreadSpecific(i))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(ThreadSpecific::getThreadName,
                Collectors.mapping(ThreadSpecific::getNums, Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if the inner aggregated object is list(or collection), then try something like:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class ThreadParallel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> input = IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        class ThreadSpecific {

            final String threadName;
            final List<String> nums;

            ThreadSpecific(int num) {
                threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                this.nums = new ArrayList<>();
                nums.add(Integer.toString(num));
            }

            public String getThreadName() {
                return threadName;
            }

            public List<String> getNums() {
                return nums;
            }
        }

        Map<String, List<String>> result = input.parallelStream()
            .map(i -> new ThreadSpecific(i))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(ThreadSpecific::getThreadName,
                Collectors.mapping(ThreadSpecific::getNums,
                    Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), nums -> nums.stream()
                        .flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
                ))));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

#### Notes

> Edit: in the sample up there I've used final keyword when initializing this object, because I know that it blocks objects reference. However does it solve my problem? Is there any better approach?

The purpose of final in reference variables are
1. Catches any accidental/unexpected reassignment to the reference variable (only reference variable is immutable)
2. The immutable property of reference variable ensures the `L`[123] caches will maintain a consistent state of this reference variable in multithreaded execution.(possibly in single threaded execution with multiple cpus).
3. This feature avoids the need for `volatile`