# Concurrent List data structure for reading file and storing objects

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Suppose I want to read the huge file where each line represents domain objects, and I need to store this information in cache. This file is read using multiple threads.
Each thread is reading certain range of lines and they will put mapped object in List. At the end when all the submitted tasks are finish, you should have full list with all objects from file.

1. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` I cant use as it creates copy on each write
   so load would be too much on memory `ArrayList` : I can use new
2. `ArrayList` for each task and insert objects read by task in its
   local `Araylist` and return it as `Future`. When all tasks are done, I
   will merge all `ArrayList` to one. Here no of `ArrayList` equal to
   number of Task I have created.

Is there any better concurrent `List` data structure I can use for storing objects ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.  Your ArrayList strategy is as good as it gets and is e.g. equivalent to what `parallelStream().collect(toList())` does.

Answer (score 0):

### CopyOnWriteArrayList may not be a correct candidate for this scenario

1. The given use-case seems to be write heavy (write-only followed by read-only)
2. `CopyOnWriteArrayList` might generally allow only a single writer at any given time (though readers can be execute concurrently)

In scenario, using `CopyOnWriteArrayList` might have worse performance than `synchronizedList` or `Vector`. [Ref SO: synchronizedList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930861/what-is-the-use-of-collections-synchronizedlist-method-it-doesnt-seem-to-syn)

For the current use case, as pointed by @Louis Wasserman, it's better to populate isolated list in each thread and then finally combine the lists.

1. the combination step can be time/space consuming due to reallocation.
2. can be slightly optimized for time/space by initializing the result list with combined size of  individual lists (avoid resizing of result internally)

Answer (score 0):

you can use guava cache/caffine,because huge file will make more gc.